# Turn /node off but keep aliases

Tags: path-aliases

I want my node page turned off.  I don't want mysite/node/3 to work.  I want it to display 404.  I tried rabbit hole and it worked but the problem ws that it also stopped the aliases from working.

Is there a solution where I can turn off the node/whatever but keep my aliases?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're on drupal 7?

Rather than trying to disable/show a 404 you could install this module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect

That will make it so that if anyone tries to access one of the "node/*" urls they will be automatically be redirected to the proper alias of the page. Would that work for what you need?

Comment: I'm on Drupal 8.  I would prefer it not exist at all.  I don't want people to  know the site uses Drupal is the goal.

Comment: Could I use this module to redirect to 404?

Answer (score -1):

You can check the path in a preprocess function using this algorithm:

**If** current route is /node/* **and** current route is not an admin/config path **then**

Redirect to 403 page

**End if**

Comment: I am not a php programmer so is there a way to do that using the site admin?